# Eclipse Clean Up and Formatting settings for Android application

Tags: android, eclipse, formatting

I’m looking for a settings file that is customized for Android development, can you point to any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the AOSP ones from here if you like: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/ide/eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Android programming/style is just java, so any sane java-formatting will work just fine.